Starting Umrah from Jeddah
We are traveling to Jeddah from the US and will stay one night there to rest up before heading to Mecca the following day to perform Umrah. Can we go into Ihram from Jeddah? Are there any penalties for starting Umrah in this way ??

You need to be in the state of ihram before reaching the meeqat, either before boarding or during the flight.
